# kineticjs resize layer based on stage width

Tags: responsive-design, kineticjs

I have a stage that resizes to the container width based on browser width (trying to make my project responsive but struggling).  I only have one layer and want the layer to resize based on the size of the stage. As of now the stage width changes with browser width but the layer width doesn't change, just gets cut off

I've tried layer.setScale(x,y) in a window.onresize function but don't have enough math sense to use this to scale the layer as the stage width changes.
I've also tried layer.setWidth(x) and used the stage width as a variable for x  in the same function but no luck.

Shouldn't the layer automatically scale with the stage?  If I adjust the canvas size in firebug the layer auto scales, but that's the only time I get the correct response...

By the way all the elements are polygons whose coordinates/points/etc are imported via svg/illustrator.  Not sure if that has anything to do with the prob...

Totally stuck...

Here's my project: http://cityunite.org/new

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to approach this problem. I'll just give my suggestion.

You should not set the width of the stage when the browser window size changes, but you should scale instead. When you first load the page, your scale is set at 1, which is (100%). When your window size changes, you should listen for that change and set the scale accordingly.

Something like this:

```
//save initial scale
var initialScale = stage.scale(); //returns {x: 1, y: 1} 
var initialWidth = $("#container").innerWidth(); // initial width
var initialHeight = $("#container").innerHeight(); // initial height

window.onresize = function(event) { // listen for change
    var width = $("#container").innerWidth(); // new width of page
    var height = $("#container").innerHeight(); // new height of page
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    var xScale =  (width  / initialWidth) * initialScale.x;  // percent change in width (Ex: 1000 - 400/1000 means the page scaled down 60%, you should play with this to get wanted results)
    var yScale = (height / initialHeight) * initialScale.y;
    var newScale = {x: xScale, y: yScale};
        console.log(newScale);
    stage.setAttr('width', width);
    stage.setAttr('height', height);    
    stage.setAttr('scale', newScale ); 
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this - I tried a simple stage.scale({x:.5,y:.5}) which throws "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scale'" error.  Tried whole numbers too, same result...

Comment: Only thing I can get to work at this point is (for example)

stage.setWidth(300);
layer.setScale(.5,.5);

Comment: try stage.setAttr('scale',{x: .5, y: .5});

Comment: that scaled the layer, but the stage is still 550 (the width of the container td)...

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle? or plunker?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle link, but this is my first, doesn't seem to work? I googled other jsfiddle/kineticjs examples and I don't see anything there either.  This is a very simplified version of my project - partly to hide my poor js skills :) http://jsfiddle.net/Qtnjz/16/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qtnjz/19/ - dont forget to do stage.draw(); So, now, when you do scaling in your javascript function, you redraw the stage so that it reflects the new size.

Comment: ah, ok - thanx for the clarification.  But the stage is still 400 regardless of what's set in the scale - I set x and y to .5 - the shape size went down by half but the stage size is still the same.  On mobile that means that if the window is <400 there will be overflow...  This is where I get confused.

Comment: The stage size will remain that way until you change it.

Comment: I updated the code, now it's closer to what you're looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/Qtnjz/23/